# Можно ли так сказать? (Фатум правды)

Tags: фразеология

Фатум правды (фатум - Рок, доля, неотвратимая судьба.) нужно для стиха

Answer (score 1):

Трудно сказать без контекста. Непонятно, что Вы имеете в виду. Что судьба правды предопределена, трагична? Если Правда у Вас в произведении - действующее лицо, у неё может быть фатум - фатальная, т.е. трагическая неизбежность, неизбежность гибели.

В других смыслах довольно странное сочетание, ведь

> (лат. fatum) - у др. римлян - олицетворение воли богов,
>   всеохватывающей неотвратимой судьбы, правящей миром и людьми.http://slovariki.org/enciklopedia-mifologii/5849

А правда по Ефремовой:

> 1. То, что соответствует действительности; истина.
> 2. Правдивость, правильность. // разг. Правота.
> 3. Порядок, основанный на справедливости

Смысл затемнён: то ли имеется в виду, что судьба справедливого порядка неизбежно трагична, то ли, наоборот, сама Правда неизбежна, только почему-то роковая, трагичная.

И стилистически слова как-то не совпадают: фатум - высокое философское, мифологическое, а правда - бытовое (в отличие от истины).

Я бы отказалась от такого сочетания.

Comment: Даже если эта самая Правда - действующее лицо, можно хоть наоборот понимать: Правда несёт свой злой рок другим, то ли хорошим (если автор этих слов демонстративно плохой), то ли грешникам, то ли всем подряд. На мой взгляд, это такая же всеконтекстная аббракадабра, как напр. "казус правды" (если речь не об одноимённой газете, которую "высек" историк Ключевский в статье с похожим названием) или какой-нибудь "кворум правды".

Comment: Согласна с Вами, в любом случае для стихотворения сочетание неподходящее.